# Miss some data in admin panel after transfer to linux server

Tags: newsletter, search-terms, transfer

I transfer my site from Windows server to Linux server and now i have some problem and miss some data in front-end and back-end.
1- some links in footer is empty and those are removed.
2- in admin panel some options like newsletter, search terms are removed and these space are empty!
How can i fix these problems?

**Edit:**

Also when i log in to the back-end i saw that the newsletter option in menu is disappear and i haven't newsletter option in menu!!!

I also set permissions to 777 but nothing has changed!!!

How can i fix this problem? Where is the problem? I searched so much about this but i couldn't get any solution for it.

Comment: How did you transfer your shop? Did you copy the full database?

Comment: @ Anna Völkl : yes, i backup full database and files.

Comment: have you checked table prefix in local.xml?

Comment: @SintuRoy : before i import copy of database in new database i removed local.xml and then do the import. is it OK or not?

Comment: These fields that the words is removed in front-end and back-end are about newsletter and search terms, just these two things.other options are OK.

Comment: Empty blocks in layout indicate suppressed exceptions. Turn on exception log and take it from there, or better yet, developer mode so it blows up on the first thing that's wrong.

Comment: @Melvyn : Can you explain more that what should i do?

Comment: @Melvyn : I check for log but it doesn't enable in admin and i enable it from System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = Yes.

Comment: You have issues across the board. If the site works perfectly on Windows I can only imagine that you've used an editor that inserts [Byte order marks](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) causing issues.