# Change in files but nothing will be happen!

Tags: transfer

I transfer my site from windows server to Linux. after this transfer when i change some files codes and then save the file and clear cache, nothing will be happen and the changes don't apply!!!

While before this transfer everything work good.

Where is the problem?

Comment: I think the problem is with file/folder permission. Please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492039/magento-apache-configuration

Comment: @NasirPerwaiz : Also after transfer site in front-end and back-end fields of newsletter and search be empty and nothing show!!! Is it possible these are be disappear because of permission?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Please try to change permissions following the guide lines available on forums.

Comment: @NasirPerwaiz: thank you so much my problem is solve but another problem that i siad you is still available. do you have any idea about this? in frontend and backend links for search and newsletter will be disappear and the place of these links are empty.

Comment: Please mark the correct answer. Also for your other issue you should probably start a new question,

Comment: Sorry just spotted your other question here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/66830/miss-some-data-in-admin-panel-after-transfer-to-linux-server?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

There could be several possible reasons for this.

Firstly clearing cache in the Magento admin may not be enough, you should delete the entire var/cache folder.

Also browser caching could be causing the problem, be sure to reload the page using a fresh cache either by clearing your browsers cache or (in Chrome at least) by using Ctrl+Shift+R.

It could also be caused by file permissions and ownership but this I would presume would cause more issues than just not showing changes made.

Try setting your permissions and ownership to the recommended ones available here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html