# Miss data in backend and frontend (dublicated)

Tags: search, newsletter

I ask this question few days ago but because i couldn't get an answer i had to ask this question again. sorry for this but i can't continue my work because of this problem.

[This is the link of my question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/66830/miss-some-data-in-admin-panel-after-transfer-to-linux-server)

I transfer my site from windows server to Linux, after that when i log in to the back-end i saw that the newsletter option in menu is disappear and i haven't newsletter option in menu!!!

Also this problem happened for search and all these links are disappear in front-end!!!

I also set permissions to 777 but nothing has changed!!!

How can i fix this problem? Where is the problem? I searched so much about this but i couldn't get any solution for it.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. If you have additional info please edit the original question.

Comment: @Marius: Ok, sorry about that, i don't know that when i edit my question it will be show on top of the question, you're right, thanks for info.